# What's wrong with the code formatter

Tags: support, code-formatting

I have been trying to format my code with the code formatter in the following answer:

[Handle Page load time in angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34197280/handle-page-load-time-angularjs/34197706#34197706)

1. The first code snippet doesn't get formatted at all.
2. I needed to include some html tags in the second snippet. But they won't show.

Trying to format seem to take more time than it takes to write the answer. Any alternatives?

Answer (score 1):

> The first code snippet doesn't get formatted at all.

Yeah, in a list you need to indent an extra 4 spaces (8 spaces in total).

> I needed to include some html tags in the second snippet. But they won't show.

Probably the same issue. Can't see what you tried, so can't really help.

The advanced editing help does have a section about formatting code (preformatted text) in lists in the [advanced lists](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#advanced-lists) section - part 4.